# .htaccess rewrite rule case sensitive

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /pages/acticle.$1.php [L]
```

Currently it is case sensitive. I need to remove this restriction. I've tried changing [L] to [NC,L] but it didn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by case insensitive? You have no cased characters in the regular expression. I think you probably have an error in your regex too, the `.` isn't escaped and is part of a negative character class...

Comment: Are you trying to rewrite everything to lowercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern doesn't contain any cased characters, so adding `NC` will have no effect. If your `RewriteRule` was for `^abcde` and you wanted it to also match `ABCDE` then adding `NC` to the rule would do this.

The pattern in your example matches any character that is not a `.` or `/` one or more times, and then adds it to the `article.$1.php` result. By default it will take whatever is matched directly so `abc`=`article.abc.php`, `ABC`=`article.ABC.php`, and so on.

I'm guessing that all of your article file names are in lowercase and that you want to rewrite `ABC` and `AbC` to `abc`, resulting in consistent naming for the files - both get `article.abc.php`. If so, there are a few options [listed on this page](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase/) - use a loop in `.htaccess` to replace uppercase with lowercase before continuing, use a `RewriteMap` in your `http.conf`, or use `mod_speling`.